# angular conditionally show div in nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div class="sunti_contain" ng-repeat="sunti in suntis track by $index">
            <div class="individual_sunti" ng-click="update_ancestor(sunti)">
                <!--needs a unique div#id via angularz-->
                <div class="sunti_content" ng-bind="sunti.content"></div>
                <div class="sunti_tags" ng-bind="sunti.tags"></div>
                <div class="sunti_author" ng-bind="sunti.author"></div>
                <div class="sunti_shortid" ng-bind="sunti.short_id"></div>
                <div class="sunti_ancestor" ng-bind="sunti.ancestor"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sunti_reply_carriage_wrapper">
                <div class="sunti_reply_carriage" ng-show="!sunti.descendents.length">
                    <div class="individual_sunti reply_carriage_sunti" ng-repeat="descendent in sunti.descendents">
                        <div class="sunti_content" ng-bind="descendent.content"></div>
                        <div class="sunti_tags" ng-bind="descendent.tags"></div>
                        <div class="sunti_author" ng-bind="descendent.author"></div>
                        <div class="sunti_shortid" ng-bind="descendent.short_id"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to only show the div.sunti_reply_carriage if there are any descendents rendered in the ng-repeat.  If there are no descendents, I don't want the div sunti_reply_carriage to appear at all.  However, the `ng-show="!sunti.descendents.length"` does not work, presumably because it's just outside/before the ng-repeat that references `descendents in sunti.descendents`

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you try with ng-show="sunti.descendents.length > 0"

Comment: Thanks I did `ng-if="sunti.descendents.length > 0"` in my wrapper div and it did the trick! =)  Add it as an answer and you gots it (if you wants it)

Comment: You can also use ng-if="sunti.descendents.length", since any number apart from 0 will always evaluate to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-show="!sunti.descendents.length"
```

Above code does not show the following code block if length is greater than zero

Ex: If sunti.descendents.length is 1 then 
    !1 is false then ng-show="false"

If sunti.descendents.length is 0 then !0 is true then ng-show="true"

So, change the expression to `ng-show="sunti.descendents.length"`

You can use ng-if as well if you want to completely remove the code block from `DOM` if the expression evaluates to false.

```
  <div class="sunti_reply_carriage" ng-show="!sunti.descendents.length">
                        <div class="individual_sunti reply_carriage_sunti" ng-repeat="descendent in sunti.descendents">
                            <div class="sunti_content" ng-bind="descendent.content"></div>
                            <div class="sunti_tags" ng-bind="descendent.tags"></div>
                            <div class="sunti_author" ng-bind="descendent.author"></div>
                            <div class="sunti_shortid" ng-bind="descendent.short_id"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sunti.descendents.length` instead of `!sunti.descendents.length`

If `length` property returns 0 then it will be hidden because it is falsey value in JavaScript, if it will return some value i.e. a `number` then it will be shown because it is truthy value in JavaScript.

If you want to show or hide you can use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives, if you want to completely remove/insert the DOM conditionally then you can use the `ng-if` directive in this case.

Using the `ng-show` directive

```
<div class="sunti_reply_carriage_wrapper">
  <div class="sunti_reply_carriage" ng-show="sunti.descendents.length">
    <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the `ng-if` directive

```
<div class="sunti_reply_carriage_wrapper">
  <div class="sunti_reply_carriage" ng-if="sunti.descendents.length">
    <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
  </div>
</div>
```